# Why does this Regex.Replace not work properly?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to replace `1234567890123456` with `************3456` with the following code:

```
Regex.Replace(xml,@"\b\d{13,16}\b", string.Concat(new String('*',12),a.Value.Substring(a.Value.Length - 4)));
```

Where `a.Value` is the number, but it just results in:

```
****************
```

Complete code:

```
//Check if value is the credit card
        if(a.Value.Length >= 13 && a.Value.Length <= 16)
                xml = Regex.Replace(xml,@"\b\d{12}(?=\d{4})\b", new String('*',12));
        else //If value is not a credit card, replace it with ***
            xml = Regex.Replace(xml,@"\b\d+\b", "***");
```

I replaced the first part of the if statement with:

```
Regex.Replace(xml, @"\b\d{13,16}\b", match => 
    String.Concat(new String('*', match.Length - 4), match.Value.Substring(match.Length - 4)));
```

but I still get `***` for the cardnum.

Here is the XML. Note the card number can be between 13 and 16 digits and I always want to keep the last 4.

```
<Details>
<CreditCard cardnum='1234567890123456'
ccv='123' 
exp='0212' 
cardType='1' 
name='joe' />
</Details>
```

long numeric;

```
    string xml = @"<Details>
<CreditCard cardnum='1234567890123456'
ccv='123' 
exp='0212' 
cardType='1' 
name='joe' />
</Details>";

XElement element = XElement.Parse(xml);
IEnumerable<XElement> elementsWithPossibleCCNumbers = 
        element.Descendants()
               .Where(d => d.Attributes()
                            .Where(a => a.Value.Length >= 13 && a.Value.Length <= 16)
                            .Where(a => long.TryParse(a.Value, out numeric))
                            .Count() == 1).Select(x=>x);


foreach(var x in elementsWithPossibleCCNumbers)
{

   foreach(var a in x.Attributes())
   {

    //Check if the value is a number
    if(long.TryParse(a.Value,out numeric))
    {
        //Check if value is the credit card
        if(a.Value.Length >= 13 && a.Value.Length <= 16)
            Regex.Replace(xml,@"\b\d{12}(?=\d{4}\b)", new String('*',12));
        else //If value is not a credit card, replace it with ***
            xml = Regex.Replace(xml,@"\b\d+\b", "***");
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Your regex asks for `{13,16}` digits, so how is it not working properly when your string has 16 digits?

Comment: @BoltClock - Sorry, not good with regex, but I had a feeling it was something like that.  Basically, I need to match a number that is 13 - 16 digits, but only replace everything but the last 4 characters.

Comment: I don't believe the regex is the issue, it works when I test it

Comment: @msmucker0527 - I have put the code where I check the length of the value and want to replace only the first 12 digits if it is between 13 and 16 digits.

Comment: If you’re getting `***`, then it’s clear that the problem is with the `if` condition (specifically, the `a.Value`), not the regex, since the `else` block is being executed.

Comment: @Douglas - I will put the complete code.

Comment: @Douglas, I don't know why the other else is being executed, I put something else in the first one to print and it does, so it is getting into the first part of the if.

Comment: But you’re not assigning anything within the `if` statement :-) Try adding an `xml = ` before your `Regex.Replace`.

Comment: @Douglas - I just noticed that, lol. Let me try again.

Comment: And replace all your `xml = Regex.Replace(xml, …` with `a.Value = Regex.Replace(a.Value, …`. To get your XML, at the end, do `xml = element.ToString()`. Otherwise, the digits at the end of your `************3456` would get replaced when the `else` statement is executed for your `ccv`.

Comment: Nice that last part did it, doing a.Value = ....  Still unclear why though, I thought the Regex.Replace will search for that the pattern and replace it with the 3rd parameter.  Thanks. It works now.

Comment: @Douglas - Ah I get it, so you saying it first finds the 16 digit number, replaces the first 12, but then finds the last 4 and replaces those with ***.

Comment: It does; however, `xml = Regex.Replace(xml,@"\b\d+\b", "***");` caused _all_ your digits to get replaced, wherever they might be located in your XML, and not just the ones within that specific attribute.

Comment: Exactly. The regex expression within the `else` statement replaces the last 4 digits with `***`.

Comment: @Douglas - which regex should I use to make since the number can be between 13 and 16. I used `\b\d{12}(?=\d{4}\b)`, but this does not do anything if the number is 13 digits long for example.

Comment: Don't worry about the last comment, I ended up using:  `a.Value =  Regex.Replace(a.Value, @"\b\d{13,16}\b", match => 
 new String('*', match.Value.Length - 4) +
 match.Value.Substring(match.Value.Length - 4));`

Comment: Use either the second or the third one from my current answer. The second regex replaces the first 9–12 characters and preserves the last 4; the third regex replaces the first 12 characters and preserves the last 1–4.

Comment: Refer to my updated answer below for some more suggestions.

Comment: Nice, I ran it and I get a consistent time of 1+ ms for 123K message which is the fastest I have seen it so far.  It initially starts at around 3 - 4 ms, but then goes to between 1 - 2 ms, staying closer to 1.  Thanks for the update.  I don't know why I used regex now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lookahead to match the trailing 4 digits but preserve them:

```
Regex.Replace(xml,@"\b\d{12}(?=\d{4}\b)", new String('*',12))
```

**Edit**: This version is closer to your code. However, rather than relying on a pre-set `a.Value`, it uses the `match` variable to allow you to apply your transformation on whatever was actually captured in your regex.

```
Regex.Replace(xml, @"\b\d{13,16}\b", match => 
    new String('*', match.Length - 4) +
    match.Value.Substring(match.Length - 4));
```

The above code assumes that you want your redacted string to have the same length as the original, and preserve the last 4 digits.

If you want to redact the first 12 digits and preserve whatever remains (1–4 digits), use:

```
Regex.Replace(xml, @"\b\d{13,16}\b", match => 
    new String('*', 12) +
    match.Value.Substring(12));
```

**Edit**: I think you already got it. But probably what you need to do is replace:

```
xml = Regex.Replace(xml, …
```

with:

```
a.Value = Regex.Replace(a.Value, …
```

**Edit**: I went through your now-complete code, and I realized that you don’t even need regex for what you’re trying to accomplish, since you’re replacing the attribute value in entirety. Here’s how I would adapt your code (with a number of changes):

```
string xml = @"
    <Details>
        <CreditCard cardnum='1234567890123456'
                    ccv='123' 
                    exp='0212' 
                    cardType='1' 
                    name='joe' />
    </Details>";

XElement element = XElement.Parse(xml);
IEnumerable<XElement> elementsWithPossibleCCNumbers =
    element.Descendants()
            .Where(d => d.Attributes()
                         .Select(a => a.Value)
                         .Any(v => v.Length >= 13 &&
                                   v.Length <= 16 &&
                                   v.All(Char.IsDigit)));

foreach (var x in elementsWithPossibleCCNumbers)
{
    foreach (var a in x.Attributes())
    {
        //Check if the value is a number
        if (a.Value.All(Char.IsDigit))
        {
            //Check if value is the credit card
            if (a.Value.Length >= 13 && a.Value.Length <= 16)
                a.Value = new String('*', a.Value.Length - 4) + a.Value.Substring(a.Value.Length - 4);
            else //If value is not a credit card, replace it with ***
                a.Value = "***";
        }
    }
}

xml = element.ToString();
```

Comment: Can you explain why my way does not work? and what do you mean by preserve them?  Also, what happens in the case, where there are less than 4 digits in the lookahead or more than 4.

Comment: I tested your code, and it works too. I assume you have the wrong value in `a.Value`.

Comment: I put in your second update and your third update, but when I run into the first part of the if statement, it puts `***` for cardnum.

Comment: Could you post your `xml`? Replace your card number with a fake number, but make sure to keep it at exactly the same length.

Comment: I will update the post.  The card number is a fake number. Don't worry.

Comment: XML looks ok. What about the code where you’re assigning the attribute to `a`?

Comment: you are partly right, I want to search the whole xml and replace part of it, but I wasn't assigning it back to xml.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and help.

Comment: What if instead of putting the whole xml string into an XElement using XElement.Parse, I find all the elements with credit cards and load those into XElement.Parse?  Wouldn't that reduce the time?  Problem is, I don't know how to select the from the beginning of the node to the end with regex.

Comment: I wouldn’t advise that; it can quickly get messy (for example, if your matched elements contain child elements or comments).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a MatchEvaluator, in this case a i've used a lambda.

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    string xml = "foo 1234567890123456 bar";
    Debug.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(xml, @"\b\d{9,12}(?=\d{4}\b)", m => new string('*', m.Value.Length)));
}
```

> `foo ************3456 bar`